# Chemfig set colour for multiple atoms

Tags: chemfig

I have a molecule where I only want to highlight two atoms in a different colour (O- and Na+). However, whenever I place both atoms in `\textcolor{olive}{O\textsuperscript{-}Na\textsuperscript{+}}` the atoms are shifted left. Is there a way of stopping this? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep = ^ 4mm _ 4mm % border gap
\begin{tabu} to 13cm {|X[cm]|}
    \hline
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{H_2 \charge{92:2pt =\:}{N}-[:-30](-[:-90,0.7]R)-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]OH}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+
    \chemfig{NaOH}
    \arrow[,1.5,thick]
    \chemfig{H_2 \charge{92:2pt =\:}{N}-[:-30](-[:-90,0.7]R)-[:30,0.75](=[:90,0.75]O)-[:-30,0.75]\textcolor{olive}{O\textsuperscript{-}Na\textsuperscript{+}}}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+ 
    \chemfig{H_2O}
    \schemestop
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note ahead: It is cleaner and shorter to write `O^{-}Na^{+}` instead of `O\textsuperscript{-}Na\textsuperscript{+}}`,

Now, the problem is, that when you wrap the two atoms, they are considered one as for the positioning. Therefore they will be shifted so that attached bond starts from the center of this compound.

Instead of

```
\textcolor{olive}{O^{-}Na^{+}}
```

you need to write

```
\textcolor{olive}{O^{-}}|\textcolor{olive}{Na^{+}}
```

Note the added pipe symbol (`|`) that splits the two atoms so that `chemfig` knows that it should attach the bond to the first one.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! might go back and add the | symbol for all my previous ones then.

Comment: You should take a look into the [`chemfig` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf). Chapter 12 has some nice practical examples, also for coloring atoms.

Comment: Yeah, I've been dipping in and out of the documentation. Admittedly not as much as I should be.